# TypeScript: Specify method returns 'this' type

Tags: typescript

Making my own mysql orm for a project. I have an abstract 'model' class that other models I make can inherit from and have all their methods and properties. My only issue at the moment is that I want to specify that a method will return the type of the class that extends it. Here's some code.

```
import db from '../db'

export default abstract class Model {
    protected static TableName: string
    protected static Columns: string[]

    protected constructor() {
        console.log('Constructing a model')
    }
                                               //Change Model here to like "type of this"
    public static async findByID(id: string): Promise<Model> {
        const query = `select ${this.columns} from ${db.name}.${this.TableName} where ${this.Columns[0]}='${id}'`

        return (await db.query(query) as Model[])[0] //Change Model here to like "type of this"
    }

    private static get columns(): string {
        return this.Columns.reduce((acc, cur, i, arr) => i !== arr.length - 1 ? acc + cur + ', ' : acc + cur, '')
    }
}
```

I am aware of the potential sql injection.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for "polymorphic `this` for static members" and it isn't currently part of the TypeScript language.  There's a GitHub issue asking for it at [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863).  It's a longstanding open issue and I don't see any obvious sign that it will ever be implemented or when.  Luckily that issue does mention some workarounds which might suffice for you:

---

In a static method, `this` refers to the type of the class constructor and not its instance type.  Instead of using a polymorphic `this` type, you can instead use a generic [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters):

```
public static async findByID<T extends Model>(
    this: { prototype: T }, id: string
) {
    const thiz = this as any as typeof Model;
    const query = 
      `select ${thiz.columns} from ${db.name}.${thiz.TableName} where ${thiz.Columns[0]}='${id}'`
    return (await db.query(query) as T[])[0]
}
```

Here we are saying that in order to call `findById()`, you need to call it as a method of an object with a `prototype` property of generic type `T`.  In TypeScript, class constructors' `prototype` property has the type of the class instance (despite this not being technically true at runtime), so if you have `class Foo extends Model {...}` then `Foo.findById()` will cause `T` to be inferred as `Foo`.  So you can treat `T` as the instance type of the subclass constructor.  And `findById()` returns a value of type `Promise<T>`.

Note the wrinkle that once you use a `this` parameter you override the inferred non-polymorphic `this` type, which is `typeof Model`.  And unfortunately there's no way to access the `protected` methods and properties from the generic `this`.  So I work around that by making a `thiz` value inside of `findById()` identical to the `this` value and manually assert that it has `typeof Model`, so you can access `columns()`, `Columns`, and `TableName`.

---

Let's make sure this works:

```
class SubModel extends Model {
    submodelProp = "foo"
}
SubModel.findByID("hello").then(s => s.submodelProp.toUpperCase())
```

Looks good to me... `SubModel.findById()` returns a `Promise<SubModel>`, as evidenced by the fact that you can access its `submodelProp` property.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3sARgLngG8BYAKHgvhSgFsQDMYBLFAcwG4zL4BHAVxAwAngAoeDDMzYBKAlBRCA2gF0yAXzJkQADwAOSGFlAAzKHwhYoORlDBZIUNGngBZJKAhF4XSrphIMcEDgeEwoDCYweAAVKwgQADlaelDJFlYfCj8AoJAQsIiogGEkCD4adAkpVhVNcl9-QLs8xFRGPjsDEWkiTO5W9FKQADoIJFYRAHIS9EkOiLZ4KHgadxAISek+jVI+3T4cCEjU8OPHIRQo4xZgACEhAEkAEQAeaPgdQJRgZzcPAD4RH1uBgABZMNAEQjwbIYAJCXQpd5qAA08CYwCq6T6PRI9X6A0w8DBTAAXvAALzE8HORxLBRLZwYBEgJDGVxrCCcfH9ZCzXgCYSU+AAAzQ6yC8AAJIQSaThsgyhU0Gp4MZ-DRpYRcMNqHQ1MMZXLhrFDolkqqAO6gwQII3g+UlJXoRQABmUagpkxlGLUkxFwMocAwfBgKHgIiglqgTCMOGG-EEokTwh6dOiKmkbtUPJ2e2YADdwggCsdWCB7KVyuhuljFniCRRg6HwyS0MMndX23BgB0QCJI2AwGiwKG0Uw0bAYD0Kf90fAAIQUqlT0YgNhg+AAWngAEZ4AB+JZD+AAakQobP8EmaMm8DkJ-Po5gt8223UdQcTngAGUDn91g+bQvh+DkPF6Hk0AOVYPAABX8XRhQAImMJAkCQj9SD-HAAIgYZrm+e5nhEJCbQgMYkOkYYwXXERnFnUJhignAYPWeCkF0aikAAVV0REYCKRx+2kLZSCAA)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in current TS 3.9, you should specify class name as it is: `Model`.